# Difference between equation formatting in article and beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, equations, article

I would like to replicate the math style of the following beamer document in article. However, when I switch the document class, the formatting of the equation (the font used) changes. I would like to incorporate certain aspects of the Pagella font for math (symbols such as the sum and integral) with Liberation Serif (as shown in the first picture), but in the article class (second picture) the letters (p for example) seem to be typeset in Pagella rather than Liberation Serif. How can I fix this to replicate the beamer style of formatting in article? [image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bernoulli Distribution}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Probability mass function
       \[ p_X(x) = p^{x}(1-p)^{\! 1-x}, \qquad x \in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace, \qquad 0 \leq p \leq 1 \]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, beamer will use letters from the text font for math. You can switch off this substitution with the `professionalfonts` theme:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Ligatures=TeX]{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bernoulli Distribution}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Probability mass function
       \[ p_X(x) = p^{x}(1-p)^{\! 1-x}, \qquad x \in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace, \qquad 0 \leq p \leq 1 \]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]